# how do I add widgets before and/or after a list in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am building an app where I want a message to be displayed at the bottom and top of the List like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGMNc.png). Ive tried to nest the ListView inside a column, but that is giving me an error. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Use a column with 3 children. Put  an expanded in the middle one and put your ListView in that.

The expanded will take up any room that is not not taken up by the top and bottom children of the column, ensuring that your ListView adapts to whatever you put around it but it always takes up every pixel that you didn't already need for the top and bottom children.